# Same table structure with different name and different use - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a better understanding of the problem, let us consider 2 simplified tables, allowance and deduction :

```
CREATE TABLE Allowance
(
    [Id]        INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Label]     VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Amount]    DECIMAL(20,3)   NOT NULL
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Deduction
(
    [Id]        INT             NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Label]     VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Amount]    DECIMAL(20,3)   NOT NULL
)
```

I am currenty working on a payroll software, and I believe the 2 tables are self-explicit and does not require further explanations. As you can see both tables have the same structure but are have different business logic. One adds to the basic salary and the other deducts.

Here is my question. Is it better to seperate the tables by business logic, as it is actually, or combine them in one table and add a new column flag, denoting the nature of a row:

- 0 for allowance
- 1 for deduction

A comparison between those two concepts would be most welcome.

Comment: It would make your querries more simple, and have better organized data to keep more tables, than to have it all in one table.  This is especially true as you would likely be using this data for different reports.

Comment: I would combine and have signed amounts (negative for deductions).

Comment: If the columns are the same then for normalisation (3nf) it would be better to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of how the data relates--if there is no true relationship in the two tables, they should be kept separate.  But, if you would need to work with the data together, such as a single SUM of both Allowances and Deductions, then combining into one table might make more sense.  Without knowing more of your design plans, it is not possible to make a good recommendation.

Comment: both tables have a many-to-many relationship with an employee table. the many-to-many table contains details on how allowances are calculated for a specific employee and in the end, i would need to have the sum of all allocation and all deductions, show them and add them to the basic salary